# Node-Webkit - Calculate hash of partially downloaded file [opensubtitles]

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, node-webkit

I'm currently calculating the hash of files with [Hasher.js](https://github.com/aetheon/node-opensubtitles-client/blob/master/lib/Hasher.js) from the [opensubtitles-client](https://github.com/aetheon/node-opensubtitles-client) node. I don't think this is an md5 hash, I believe it is a [custom algorithm](http://trac.opensubtitles.org/projects/opensubtitles/wiki/HashSourceCodes) from OpenSubtitles.

With Hasher.js, to calculate the hash of a file by file path I'd use:

```
require("Hasher.js").getHash(file).done(function(hash){

    fileHash = hash; // this is the file hash

});
```

*(where "file" is the file path)*

This works for fully downloaded video files (and I think even for files that are at least 60-70% downloaded).

If less then about 60% of the file is available, it always gets the same hash (although this is not the correct hash), and after the (probably) 60% it always gets the correct one.

Is there something I'm missing, are there any node-webkit, node.js or pure javascript implementations that could always calculate the hash correctly for partially downloaded files?

Or is this a normal limitation of calculating hashes from partial files? If so, why does it always return the same 2 hashes (the wrong one and the correct one)? How much of the file would it really need to get the correct hash directly?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think a hashing algorithm is supposed to work over the entirety of the file. But then again, you can partially apply an MD5 hash, but it will change as you keep adding 512-bit chunks to the hashing function. Same idea for partially downloaded files. The purpose of any good hashing algorithm is to ensure that even 1 bit of difference to a buffer of data will yield an entirely different hash.

Comment: This is not an md5 hash, I think it is a [custom algorithm](http://trac.opensubtitles.org/projects/opensubtitles/wiki/HashSourceCodes). I updated the question.

Comment: I don't know why you are getting the behavior you are, perhaps the data being written to the file is being buffered in memory, but as mentioned above a good hash will calculate a different hash for different file sizes and data. You should only be able to get the correct hash once the file has fully downloaded. You could chunk the data into smaller parts, and have a different hash for each chunk, and check them as the chunks download.

Comment: @Jaruba: I'm fully aware of the fact that it isn't MD5. I just used MD5 as an example, just to say that you can partially apply MD5, but I understand that there are many other hashing algorithms out there.

Answer (score 1):

from http://trac.opensubtitles.org/projects/opensubtitles/wiki/HashSourceCodes:

> Hash code is based on ​Media Player Classic. In natural language it
>   calculates: size + 64bit chksum of the first and last 64k (even if
>   they overlap because the file is smaller than 128k).

This means that unless you have downloaded the first and last 64kb of the file, you will most probably not get the correct opensubtitles hash.